# Can't insert some arabic characters

Tags: input-encodings, arabic

I would to insert some arabic characters like `﴾` but I can't, I get this error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ﴾ (U+FD3F)
```

I tried `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` and `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` but also doesn't work.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ucs}

\begin{document}
﴾
\end{document}
```

I use TeXLive distribution.

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Comment: What did you try with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` ?

Comment: Basically you need a font that contains a glyph for `﴾` — are you aware of such a font that exists on your system? If not, what do you want to happen when [that character](https://codepoints.net/U+FD3E) is entered?

Answer (score 1):

By looking up [fontchart_arabic.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/arabic/arabi/arabi/texmf/doc/latex/arabi/fontchart_arabic.pdf) or the file `texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmap/lae.cmap`, it appears that this character `﴾` = [U+FD3E ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS](https://codepoints.net/U+FD3E) is encoded at position (hex) `5D` = (octal) `135`. So we can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FD3E}{\char"5D}` or (with the package [`newunicodechar`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar)) `\newunicodechar{﴾}{\char"5D}}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FD3E}{\char"5D\relax}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ucs}

\begin{document}
﴾
\end{document}
```

[image: typeset]

Of course possibly it ought to have been working already, and I don't know why it doesn't. Personally I find it simpler to use XeTeX/LuaTeX for typesetting non-Latin scripts, instead of dealing with all this.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. But I have same error with other characters, where can I find hex code of these characters to use this command `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{}{\char"}` with them.

Comment: @OussamaHe What are the other characters? Can you give a sample text? Also see the [arabi user guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/arabi/user_guide.pdf). And have you considered using a Unicode engine (XeTeX/LuaTeX) with a system font?