# Can't compile an arabic file using LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, input-encodings, arabic

I have an article written in arabic I want to use tex to get a PDF file, but I can't compile the file (I'm using LuaLaTeX), I get this error:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.137 \ifcase#1\or
����� \or ������
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.
```

This is an extract from the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{ucs}
\begin{document}
و يقول شيخ الإسلام ابن تيميَّة رحمه الله في «منهاج السنَّة» في...
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use fontenc. Where's your `fontspec` definition with appropriate font?

Comment: Is this related/a dupe of your earlier question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373958/cant-insert-some-arabic-characters

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE example using *Amiri* as main font and works with `XeLaTeX`.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}

\begin{document}
و يقول شيخ الإسلام ابن تيميَّة رحمه الله في «منهاج السنَّة» في...
\end{document}
```

Comment: This what I got after long time of compiling 
<img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6r8tf8S_F3NYkhMdWhoVHIzQUU/view?usp=sharing">

Comment: can you post the `logfile` of the compilation? if your text is bilingual you must set up the other language by adding                                                           \setotherlanguage{english}

Comment: So these are the tex file and log file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6r8tf8S_F3NR2FTcFNNbnFVZUE?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `"Ligatures=TeX"` instead of `"Mapping=tex-text"` since you are running luatex and not xelatex

Comment: doesn't work, this is what I got https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6r8tf8S_F3NOU5mUzlsaXVOLW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you try using `xelatex` ? which version of texlive do you have ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `xelatex` and it works fine, my texlive version: `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`

Comment: This should work with luatex 1.0x so TeX Live 2016 (> 08 i guess) if it's mandatory for you to work with luatex.     If you are satisfied with my answer then please mark it as a good one ;)